# Restore Files from Client Computer Backups (Windows Server Backup) -Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

A laptop connected to the domain with some critical files died the other week, and I'm having trouble restoring the files. The laptop is sent away for repairs, but in the meantime I need the files from the backup. I have automatic backups configured in Windows Server Essentials 2012, and several client backups from the laptop.

Is there a way to restore the files from the client backup onto the server? I know older versions of WSB used regular zip or CAB archives that I could manually browse, but it seems WSE2012 save sector data instead. Is there way to still mount/browse the .dat files?

Comment: Restore to different laptop, get files, nut-punch developer who's storing critical files on laptop?

Comment: that sounds do-able. Except - I don't have a laptop with similar enough hardware to do a full restore. If I join a new laptop to the domain how do I restore files from a backup from a different laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Restore Files and Folders Wizard" as mentioned in the vendor's documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj593197.aspx#BKMK_RestoreFilesAndFolders).
You may also find this document useful;

"[Restore a full system from an existing client computer backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713539.aspx)"